# Adding UTM parameters in WhatsApp share button, how?

Tags: wordpress, utm-parameters

I'm using this code to generate the WhatsApp share button:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?> <?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?>">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

I want to add also `?utm_source=whatsapp` in the URL.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using WordPress based on the `get_post_permalink()` so try replacing `<?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?>` with `<?php echo get_post_permalink().'?utm_source=whatsapp'; ?>` to append the attribute onto the link.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your reply.

I tried your code.

It does append the attribute to the link... but... it doesn't autofill in Whatsapp, after you hit share, selected the contact, it just stays emtpy.

The one that I provided does autofill the text in Whatsapp... but sadly with no utm in it, so no way of tracking it (or let's say not so easy).

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=[TITLE] : [Link]?utm_source=site%26utm_medium=social_share%26utm_content=whatsapp" data-action="[Link]"></a>
```

This works for me

Comment: How is it "work"? Whatsapp contact opened - it is obvious. But how and where do you use utm parameters?

Answer (score -2):

You should url encode the = to %3D and it will work.
And any & to %26.

Comment: I agree that some escaping needs to be done, but I would think it would have to be anything within the post title and within the permalink URL.   Escaping the equals that separates the parameter from the value would not be correct.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting a correct solution. Give the explanation of the OP, replacing = with %3D solves his issue. We don't have more info. Assuming the function(s) also need escaping is based on nothing, who knows they are already escaped?

Comment: Maybe you can explain it further?  It sounds like you are suggesting `whatsapp://send?text%3DTHE+TITLE` which makes what had been a `text` parameter with a value into a single parameter whose name includes the equals sign and value.